# Dojo & StackController/StackContainer

Tags: javascript, dojo

I'm using StackContainer as a menu but I'm having a problem to attach custom onclick events on "tabs" in stackcontainer.

My app is basically laid out like this:

```
header
subheader
content
```

Header has the stackcontroller tabs and content obviously shows the content. However when I click any of the tab elements in the header, I want to run a function that changes subheader accordingly. Now how I can do this? Content switching works great so no problems there.

I'm using ContentPanes as tab elements and I tried to put onclick straight on them and I tried with dojo.connect - no luck. I have experience with jQuery & plain JS but I'm a dojo newbie so excuse me if I'm missing something really obvious :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this will be to use the pub/sub mechanism built into the widget.

On child selection the StackContainer will publish:

```
dojo.publish(this.id+"-selectChild", [page]);
```

where page is the child widget being selected.

So you should use:

```
dojo.subscribe(myStackId, function(/* dijit */ selectedChild) {
    // use the selectedChild to do what you want
});
```

As an aside, dijits provide normalised events which are camel cased. So you could connect to the onclick event of the dijit, but to do this you should use 'onClick'. However, you wouldn't necessarily guarantee that a child had been selected if you used this approach.

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/publish.html

Comment: That works. I didn't realize how much Dojo uses pubsub technique but it really is very smart way to tie things together.

Comment: Yeah, only problem is it's not very well documented in the API IMO